# Php mysqli_query connection link from other php file

Tags: php, mysql

I used to use **mysql_query** to execute a query, but I found new function which is **mysqli_query** which ask for **two parameters** 1) is Connection link and 2) is query. 

 How to create a Connection link from other php file like congif.php file. I have displayed an example, I just need a solution that how to travel connection link in to all over project by including config.php file.


**1) Config.php**

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","");

mysqli_select_db($conn,"abc");
```

**2) users.php**

```
include_once "config.php";

class users {

function checkuser($username,$pass){

    $select = "SELECT userid,pass FROM users WHERE userid='{$username}' AND pass='{$pass}' LIMIT 1";

        $qry = mysqli_query($conn,$select);
        $result = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
        if ($result > 1 ){ return true; } ELSE { return false; }
    }

}
```

How to travel **$conn** all over the project.thence I can use $conn in all kind of functions like mysqli_query or mysqli_num

Comment: and more thing you are using mysqli_function wrong? it thats is your problem let me know

Comment: Seems you are a beginner / learner. Better learn PDO as it is new and has lots of features.

Comment: I use `PDO` personally, but `mysqli_` is perfectly acceptable for both beginners and advanced users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add it to your `__construct()`.

```
class users {
        protected $con;

        public function __construct() {
                include_once("config.php");
                $this->con = $conn;
            }

        public function checkuser($username,$pass){
                $select = "SELECT userid,pass FROM users WHERE userid='{$username}' AND pass='{$pass}' LIMIT 1";

                 $qry = mysqli_query($this->con,$select);
                 $result = mysqli_num_rows($qry);
                 if ($result > 1 ){ return true; } ELSE { return false; }
             }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **config.php** is wrong

it should be

```
$conn=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "abc") or die(mysqli_error($conn));
//I added the error just to check any error.
```

and than you can simply use include_once the way you are using.

or you can see the basic structurure

```
$conn=  mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "YourPassword", "YourDatabaseName") 
or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Answer (score 0):

in your config.php file, you may want to define your connection as:

```
global $conn;
```

Also, a function in config.php or another script file included after config.php to execute the query will make your job easier:

```
function query($sql){
  return mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```